# Why my side effect action can't recognize my return action type property?

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-store, ngrx-effects

I am trying to setup SideEffect for my authentication store. every time I fire the action (`TrySignIn`) I receive the following error:

> "AuthEffects.authSignin" dispatched an invalid action
>
> ERROR TypeError: Actions must have a type property

My understanding, from the error type, is that my return action does not have a type property, which is not the case here, I am returning two actions, `SIGNIN` and `SET_TOKEN` and both of them have type properties.

I appreciate it if someone can tell me what am I doing wrong here,

#### Edit:

I reproduced the error [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-awomkw), you will be able to see the same errors I receive in the console.

I am posting the relevant code for my implementation,

**My AuthActions**

```
export class TrySignin implements Action {
  readonly type = TRY_SIGNIN;

  constructor(public payload: Credentials) {}
}

export class Signin implements Action {
  readonly type = SIGNIN;
}

export class SetToken implements Action {
  readonly type = SET_TOKEN;

  constructor(public payload: string) {}
}
```

My SideEffect,

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthEffects {
  @Effect()
  authSignin = this.actions$
    .ofType(AuthActions.TRY_SIGNIN)
    .map((action: AuthActions.TrySignin) => {
      return action.payload;
    }).switchMap(
      (authData: Credentials) => {
         return (this.httpService.postRequest('/Account/Login', (authData)));
      })
      .map(
        (res) => {
          console.log(res['authToken']);
          return [
            {
              type: AuthActions.SIGNIN
            },
            {
              type: AuthActions.SET_TOKEN,
              payload: res['authToken']
            }
          ];

        }
      );
```

And in my component, I fire my action,

```
login() {
    this.store.dispatch(new authActions.TrySignin(this.loginForm.value));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Effects modify a dispatched action before it hits the store. It looks like you're modifying the action in-flight to transform (map) it to

```
      return [
        {
          type: AuthActions.SIGNIN
        },
        {
          type: AuthActions.SET_TOKEN,
          payload: res['authToken']
        }
      ];
```

^^ This is an array. It does not adhere to the `Action` interface (and it does not have a type property).

If you edit this to look like

```
      return {
          type: AuthActions.SIGNIN
        }
```

Does it work?

#### Update

Hoisted from the comments: if you want your action to dispatch additional actions, use `mergeMap()`. It adds to the existing observable, rather than replacing it.

Comment: yes, it seems to work, no errors, but how can I return the second action `AuthActions.SET_TOKEN` with its payload?

Comment: @JSON I've done that before but I don't remember off the top of my head. I think using `mergeMap()` will let you. Actually, if I remember correctly, one of the examples on NGRX's website shows you how to.(maybe..)

Comment: @JSON Ya I think it's mergeMap, the more I think about it. I believe mergeMap adds to an existing observable, rather than replacing it. I'd start there

Comment: if you please can add it to your answer for future reference